# How to display a tooltip with the value of a slider field in a Classic UI AEM dialog?

Tags: widget, slider, aem, xtype

I use Slider xtype in `dialog.xml`

Is it possible to automatically display the value of this slider? for example - like a tooltip when the value changes

```
<slider
   jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
   fieldLabel="Tile Background Transparency"
   name="./slider"
   width="{Long}200"
   value="42"
   increment="1"
   minValue="0"
   maxValue="100"
   xtype="slider"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sliderfield` xtype which provides this functionality.

The `useTips` property allows to enforce the desired behaviour.

```
<slider
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Tile Background Transparency"
    name="./slider"
    width="{Long}200"
    value="42"
    increment="1"
    useTips="true"
    minValue="0"
    maxValue="100"
    xtype="sliderfield"/>
```

[image: AEM Classic UI sliderfield tips]

Check out [the docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html) for more information.