# How to display the value chosen from Sliderfield xtype on the dialog?

Tags: aem

I am using sliderfield xtype allowing authors to chose a value. Currently authors are not aware of current chosen value. Is there a way to show the value as either a bubble as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/RangeBubble/) or a separate text value outside the slider? Below is the dialog.

```
               <backgroundAlpha
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Background Alpha (Opacity)"
                    increment="1"
                    maxValue="{Long}100"
                    minValue="{Long}0"
                    name="./backgroundAlpha"
                    useTips="{Boolean}true"
                    xtype="sliderfield"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AEM CQ: Slider xtype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147453/aem-cq-slider-xtype)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am looking for an extension of slidefield explained in above question that ll show its current value on dialog load before the user starts sliding.

Answer (score 0):

I Just used the below code to get the property and able to display in page. And the default dialog already shows the selected value.

```
<% if(properties.get("sliderfield")!=null){%> Here is your sliderfield FIELD DATA:: <%=properties.get("sliderfield")%> <%}%>
```

[image: SliderDialog]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your example shows to display on component page. My question is how to render on the dialog? If you take the mouse off the slide, the value disappears. How to make slider show its value on the dialog only?

Comment: you have to override the /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/source/widgets/form/SliderField.js for that you can create a custom widget where you need to have your own CQ.Ext.slider.Tip(). ( Example in the EXT JS slider.removeListener('dragend', me.hide, me); to have the tip to enabled without hiding after the slider action.)

Comment: There's a similar xtype called `sliderfield` that does it OOTB

Comment: Thanks @toniedzwiedz, I am using sliderfield indeed. But the value pops up only when user slides. I want to show current value when dialog opens on the slider (or after he selects)

Comment: Thanks @VAr, custom xtype is possible. I was wondering if anyone has already implemented and can I have a sample or is there a property otb that I can enable to achieve this.

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash I see. Please note that your question does not mention `sliderfield` (it's about `slider`, a similar but different xtype) or the fact that you want to display the value immediately when the dialog opens and not just after selecting a value.